# Detect lines not connected to the main network R

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, line, intersection, sf

How could I autodetect lines not touching the principal net in R? In this example I would like to remove the top right line.

[image]

I already know how to select and delete lines by their lengths but that will not work as I need those little lines that work as connectors between points and net. 
This is what I'm tying so far: try to detect the intersections between the layer of lines with himself and get rid of those that just have one intersect, what I guess means that they are just intersecting with themselves.

```
l <- readOGR("./Layers/Lines.gpkg")
st_intersects(st_as_sf(l),st_as_sf(l))
```

It would be nice any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved using this code:

```
#remove lines not conected to 
l <- readOGR("./Layers/Lines.gpkg")
inter <- st_intersects(st_as_sf(l),st_as_sf(l), sparse = TRUE)
ls <- ls[lengths(inter)>1,] #select lines intersecting with more than themselves
```

[image]